# Is there a C# idiom to create then add to a collection?

Tags: c#, idioms

Say I have this:

```
private list<myClass> myCollection;
```

Is there a programming idiom to shorten this very common statement combination into a single statement? :

```
   if (myCollection == null)
      myCollection = new list<myCollection>();

   myCollection.Add(someInstanceOfMyClass);
```

The idiom could be described as "create if necessary, then add to it"

TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply create at declaration?:

```
private readonly List<myClass> myCollection = new List<myCollection>();
```

Instantiating a single list is not a time or memory consuming thing. (Might be different if you had thousands of these and wanted lazy instantiation).

Comment: No, I don't have thousands and don't need lazy instantiation. So thanks for your quick response and sorry for the newbie question.  (Although it is consistent with my profile.)

Answer (score 1):

You *could* make something like this:

```
private List<myClass> myCollection { get {
   if (_myCollection == null) _myCollection = new List<myCollection>();
   return _myCollection;
}}
private List<myClass> _myCollection;
```

Then later:

```
myCollection.Add(someInstance);
```

Which will call the getter, which checks for null.

But it's probably better to just create the list once as per [Mitch Wheat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10973897/369)